# Extracting a graph from a map API in JAVA

Tags: android, google-maps, graph, maps, extract

My goal is to take several locations from the map and make a graph of them according to the paths between the locations. the locations will be the vertices and the paths between two locations will be the edges.

Draft of the idea:

[image]

I'm not so familiar with google maps API or another maps API's, but I will be happy if you guys could help me find a way to achieve this goal

Comment: Post the problematic piece of code directly here as a snippet and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. [Google's direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or [Graphhopper](https://graphhopper.com/) to get the route, and then render them yourself through `Canvas` to a `Bitmap`.